# Selectively disable asset.digest in Rails 3, so external site can include stylesheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, tumblr

**The aim:**

I would like a Tumblr blog to pull CSS from a Rails app's asset directory.

This means I can use SASS, Compass and other sitewide CSS to generate the styling.

This also means if anything is updated in low-level CSS, `tumblr.css` will be regenerated along with the regular `cap deploy`, and Tumblr's appearance will change automatically.

**The problem:**

The Rails 3 asset pipeline adds a hash to the filename, e.g.:

`tumblr-c6ec969ce054623163b9404f6c8330e9.css`

Therefore the Tumblr template can't include it unless I update the URL manually every time it changes.

Is there a way to either selectively disable `asset.digest` for one file, or to explicitly generate a single CSS file from SASS, without going through the whole asset pipeline? Or maybe to generate an automatic alias or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will not have to disable the digests at all.

When Rails precompiles the assets, it adds digests to all the files. However it also creates identical files without digests. So both the following files will load the same css:

- `tumblr-c6ec969ce054623163b9404f6c8330e9.css`
- `tumblr.css`

If you check the `public/assets` directory after precompilation you should see both files.

Hope this makes helps.

Comment: Hmm, this definitely isn't the case with my deployment. There are _no_ files in `public/assets` without digests. Perhaps I have broken something in pre-compilation then?

Comment: Are you running it with the correct environment? Like this: `rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: In Capistrano you may have to add `set :rails_env, :production` to your recipe.

Comment: Hiya, yes I was running it on the server with `RAILS_ENV=production`. Capistrano seems to deploy to production by default, but I tried adding the line you suggest. Didn't seem to help. I should clarify: if I delete the shared `public/assets` directory, Capistrano correctly rebuilds everything in it on the next deploy, but it all has digests appended! Deeply confused as to how I've broken the default behaviour you describe!

Comment: What happens if you run `rake assets:precompile:nodigest` manually?

Comment: Hi Phil, I have now fixed this by the rather blunt expedient of upgrading to Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.3. So `rake assets:precompile:nodigest` does work now, and the regular Capistrano deploy generates the right files. Unfortunately I have not been very scientific, so I cannot pinpoint what was broken before. Thanks for all your help though - your answer made it clear that this was an error somewhere in my environment rather than due to how Rails works.

Comment: N.B. I have accepted, as under normal circumstances this is the right answer!

Comment: @PhilBottomley it seems like ```rake assets:precompile``` in ```Rails 4``` doesn't generate files without digests could you help me?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703468/static-route-to-coffee-asset

Comment: You seem to be correct: there are some recommendations here: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49

Answer (score 4):

In Rails 4 it seems that the asset precompile no longer does both the digest and non-digest filenames, only the filenames with the digest get compiled. The best option now to precompile assets without a digest hash is to use the Non Stupid Digest Assets gem:

```
https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets
```

Hopefully they add this to the Rails project as a standard feature in Rails 5.