# Static url to asset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, assets

I have a script `my_pub_script.js.coffee` written with `coffeescript` and I want to make it public so anybody can download it on `example.com/scripts/my_pub_script.js`

I can put any files in `/public` but this is `coffee` and I had to pass it through asset pipeline to properly compile it to `js`.
But if I compile my script it will have a name with fingerprint suffix like `my_pub_script-e55bd5e3eb82fa4e8034af2883dc37e8.js` so **I don't know the current link** to it.

Sure I have many other files that I want to pass through assets pipeline normally.

How I can make a static route to some coffeescript asset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `rails '>= 3.1.1, < 4.0.0'` there was both digest and non-digest versions of every assets in result of `rake assets:precompile`.

In `rails '>= 4.0.0'` according to [this](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49) we have only digest versions without any possibility to get non-digest assets.

Now we have [several solutions](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/49#issuecomment-26020304). I prefer to use the gem [non-stupid-digest-assets](https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets)
which adds non-digest versions of assets for `rake assets:precompile`.

Answer (score -1):

Fingerprinting is enabled by default for production and disabled for all other environments. You can enable or disable it in your configuration through the `config.assets.digest` option.

So in production.rb file, just do,

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

So, your problem will be resolved. But, if you want the above file only without finger printing, I'm not having the answer.

for more details about fingerprinting, please refer [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark)

Hope that helps you..

Comment: Yes, I have many other files that I want to pass through assets pipeline normally.

Comment: Hey, please put a comment while down-voting answers. What I said above is true. Please comment..